# vi/nvi (FreeBSD) How to make an abbreviation to a shell command?

Tags: abbreviations, nvi

I know how to make an abbreviation to a command in vim. For example to print the date, I have this in .vimrc:

```
iabbrev mydate <C-R>=strftime("%a %d/%m/%Y")
```

Now I'm running a VM with FreeBSD as a guest. Base system has good old vi/nvi.

I can print the date with:

```
:r !date "+%a %d/%M/%Y"
```

But how can I make an abbreviation to the above command?

I've tried:

```
:ab mydate :r !date "+%a %d/%M/%Y"
```

but this will not work.

Any ideas?

**EDIT 1**

Correction. In vim I actually have:

```
iabbrev mydate <C-R>=strftime("%a %d/%m/%Y")
```

not

```
:ab date_ ^[:r!date -I^MkJA
```

The rest of the question stands.

**EDIT 2**

D. Ben Knoble,

I made a mess with the original question.

To clarify:

I'm using vi/nvi on FreeBSD. (Version 2.1.3 (2015-04-08) The CSRG, University of California, Berkeley.)

"iabbrev" and "nnoremap" are Vim commands, not vi/nvi commands.

Comment: You need to escape the `%`

Comment: In the future, please use [edit] to update the question.

Comment: See my edits regarding historical compat.

Comment: Also consider installing Vim on your FreeBSD VM. It's definitely available from the Ports repository and should be pretty easy to install.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a solution:

I put this in ~/.nexrc:

```
ab mydate ^[:r !date "+\%a \%d/\%m/\%Y"^MkJA
```

Where:

`^[` = <kbd>CTRL+v</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd>

and

`^M` = <kbd>CTRL+v</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Many thanks to Antony_ on Freenode channel ##vi for the solution.

Comment: A precision for those who are not used to the notation used above:
``^[`` is what appears on the screen and ``CTLR+v ESC`` is what you should actually type.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a mapping for it

```
nnoremap keys :read !date...<CR>
```

Or you can use `<C-o>`:

```
iabbrev keys <C-o>:read !date...<CR>
```

For historical (`vi`) compatibility, I believe one can do `map!` and `abbrev`—these are listed in Vim under `:help vi-features` as supported vi features (though I cannot find them in the [POSIX spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), they are mentioned). Note that abbreviations are used in Insert, Replace, and Command mode, while `map!`s are used in Insert and Command mode. Choose `keys` carefully. You'll probably also need <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert the literal, instead of `<CR>`.

Peter points to in the comments `<C-r>=get(systemlist('date'),0`—not sure how this interacts with pure vi, however.

Comment: Or use `<c-r>` with expression register, e.g. `iabbrev keys <c-r>=get(systemlist('date ...'),0)<cr>`